# Nested first-of-type and first-letter

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a drop-cap feature using css selectors `first-of-type` and `first-letter`.

This is for a WordPress site and the issue I'm having is that some posts could be build using visual composer while others could be built using the standard editor.

That means that the inner html structure of the content changes (divs are added) and my css rule `.post_content > p:first-of-type:first-letter { font-size: 24px }` doesn't work any more.

```
<div class="post_content">
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <p>Another line</p>
    <p>Another line</p>
    <p>This shouldn't be dropcaped</p>
    <p>Another line</p>
    <p>Another line</p>
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="post_content">
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
            <div class="vc_column-inner">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <p>Hello world</p>
                            <p>Another line</p>
                            <p>Another line</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
            <div class="vc_column-inner">
                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                            <p>This shouldn't be dropcapped</p>
                            <p>Another line</p>
                            <p>Another line</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i remove the immediate children selector (>) all paragraphs get the style applied.

Is there something I'm missing ? Is there any way I could achieve the desired effect ?

Thanks!

PS: Actually, the simplified version works, I just tested it in a fiddle. But the real html is this:
https://jsfiddle.net/s8ajo1hw/ 
and you can see the issue with the `<p>` tag being selected multiple times.

PPS: After a bit of fiddling, I found out that the issue was from `p` nested in separate `div`s that are nested in the main `post_content`.  Simplified version: https://jsfiddle.net/9v9j3amz/

As you can see from the fiddle, the behaviour is quite weird.
Any insight on why this happens is much appreciated!

Comment: Just make your selector more specific...that's an awful lot of nesting you have going on there.

Comment: It's what the Visual Composer plugin outputs if you want to add a text element. It add a container, a row, a column minimum. If the user plays around with inner columns things get way more nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
.post_content:first-letter{
  font-size:34px;
  color: red;
}
```

The complex query was not working because :first-letter applies the style on the first letter from the selector.

Comment: This is the simplest solution, but as I've found out, I had an issue of it not working because one of the containing div's had a float:left set.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you to achieve desired effect. Add this `CSS` to your stylesheet..

```
    div.post_content * > p:first-of-type:first-letter {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
```

It will select all nested elements no matter how many. This asterisk `*` is a wildcard here.

**Update:**
I have tinkered a bit with your code but actually there are way too many nested elements and they can grow. So if you don't mind javascript add this snippet to the end of your file. Will solve your problem pretty good for now. Work on your both fiddles.

```
<style>
    .my-class:first-letter {
        font-size: 60px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("wpb_wrapper")[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    el.className = 'my-class';
</script>
```

Comment: I already tried that one. As you can check on the fiddle i added, you can see it doesn't work.

Comment: Edited the main question, added simplified fiddle link if you want to check it out.

Comment: Sometimes a solution is way too easy and we get complicated... :) Diegys solution works check it out... Nice Work! @Diegys

Answer (score 0):

Since `::first-letter` applies to the "first letter of the first line of a block-level element" you can just target the `.post_content`:

```
.post_content:first-letter {
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqZYgy